# Tool (similar to e.g. Firepath) for matching XPaths in multiple frames

Tags: xpath, firebug, frames

I currently use Firepath to test my XPaths. Firepath gives matches from the currently focused frame only. Is there a similar tool that can give me all matches in all frames on the page?

Comment: I have the same problem : I cannot test a valid Xpath expression because of the frame :/

Answer (score 2):

You may right-click the frame and select 'open in a new window' (or tab). There you'll be able to test your xpaths. 
Now I see what you're trying to do... match all elements within all frames. I don't think so. Give it a try to Xpath checker, a firefox plugin.